# Problem Running Ant Script In Netbeans 6.1

Tags: file, netbeans, ant, load

I tried to import my ant script. And it successful. But when i compile it. I got this error:

```
run-selected-file-in-src:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\sounds\voice.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFileReader.java:205)
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1162)
        at SimpleSoundPlayer.<init>(SimpleSoundPlayer.java:35)
        at SimpleSoundPlayer.main(SimpleSoundPlayer.java:12)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(ByteArrayInputStream.java:89)
        at SimpleSoundPlayer.main(SimpleSoundPlayer.java:16)
D:\Windows\My Document\Latihan\Java\allsrc\ch04src\nbproject\ide-file-targets.xml:7: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is my folder structure

```
root
+-build(all *.class store here)
+-images
+-nbproject(netbeans create it)
+-sounds(voice.wav where i want to load)
+-src(all *.java - When i compile. All *.class will store to "build" folder)
+-build.xml
```

My question is why the class file(SimpleSoundPlayer.class) didn't find "..\sounds\voice.wav". But when i tried it from command-line "java SimpleSoundPlayer" it fine.

Why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURE IT OUT!!!
Special Thx to "JB Nizet". Because him i know why it didn't find the wav file. So i just search how to change the default location(this case in root) netbeans to compile(I want netbeans to compile from "build" folder).

The key is in nbproject/ide-file-target.xml

```
root
+-build(all *.class store here)
+-images
+-nbproject(netbeans create it)
+-sounds(voice.wav where i want to load)
+-src(all *.java - When i compile. All *.class will store to "build" folder)
+-build.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="../build" name="chap04 - Sound Effects and Music-IDE">
    <!-- TODO: edit the following target according to your needs -->
    <!-- (more info: http://www.netbeans.org/kb/41/freeform-config.html#runsingle) -->
    <target name="run-selected-file-in-src">
        <fail unless="run.class">Must set property 'run.class'</fail>
        <java classname="${run.class}" failonerror="true" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="build"/>
                <pathelement location="."/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
```

So i just change on `<project basedir=".."` to `<project basediir="../build"` where i want netbeans to compile. With this change netbeans will compile that file in "build" folder. AND... WOWWW... That file run correctly :D

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use a relative path to load the file : `..\sounds\voice.wav`. When you do this, your app is very fragile, because it must be launched from a specific directory to work correctly.

I suspect that NetBeans launches your app from the root folder instead of launching it from the src or build folder.

I would recommend to put the voice.wav in your sources, so that it's copied into the build directory, along with your class files. Then you may load the file using the classloader, thanks to a call to [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Hm... Thx for your replay. Do you have another solution to keep my "sound" folder in root? I mean not move it. Does it possible?